# I Call SmartContract Token ERC20, Why Show Hashing Output?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I do not know why with this, even though in the previous version (web3 + Metamask) can issue real data. But now used as hashing (output). I took the example in the code and output below (to get the TotalSupply on the ERC20 Token):

Output : 0x18160ddd

```
const contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
const total_supply = contractInstance.totalSupply.getData();
console.log(total_supply);
```

How to showing real data? In a sense it doesn't come out hashing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getData()` returns the ABI-encoded input you would have to send to the smart contract to invoke that method.

If you want to actually call the smart contract, use `.call()` instead.

Comment: how do you do it? Is this like contractInstance.totalSupply.call() ? I did not succeed (error)

Comment: The exact syntax depends on whether you're using web3.js 0.2.x, web3.js 1.0.x, a Truffle contract instance, etc. My guess based on your other code is that this is web3.js 0.2.x, so it should probably justs be `contractInstance.totalSupply()`.